# Connection with FluentNHibernate

Tags: mysql, fluent-nhibernate

I'm having some problem with connection to MySQL Database using FluentNHibernate.It doesn't work. This is code:

```
public static ISessionFactory Configure()
{
    return Fluently
        .Configure()
        .Database(
            MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(m =>
                m.Server("mn01.webd.pl")
                    .Database("database")
                    .Username("user")
                    .Password("pass")                   
                )
         )
         .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Hala>())
         .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

I'm using remote hosting to store a database system. When I'm using a ADO.NET with the same ConnectionString data... well it works. I've no idea what's happening ?

Comment: Are you having any error messages or something? You're not accually openning the session for the section factory in this function, I'm assuming your doing it elsewhere, right?

Comment: No I didn't have any errors or warnings. Finally, I used ADO.NET.